# Error: ';' expected

Tags: java, compiler-errors

This may be stupid. But, i'm getting an error saying: "error: ';' expected If(!Temp_List.isEmpty())" when trying to build the below code. I can't figure it out. Could anybody please help to sort out this problem ?

Thanks in advance !

```
public class Error_Case
{

    ArrayList<String> Temp_List=new ArrayList<String>();

    private class CHECK_CLASS
    {
        public void Check()
        {
            If(!Temp_List.isEmpty())
            {
                System.out.println("Temp_List is not empty !");
            }
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {
        CHECK_CLASS new_Class=new CHECK_CLASS();
        new_Class.Check();
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Error_Case controller=new Error_Case();
        controller.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: `if`, not `If`. Syntax errors are offtopic here, keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: Consider using a programming editor, most modern editors will show you syntax errors, like If in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Java keywords are lowercase. Therefore, `If` should be `if`:

```
if (!Temp_List.isEmpty())
{
    System.out.println("Temp_List is not empty !");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The java Programming language is Case Sensitive.you dont write  `If`like this . write like in lower case `if` this.

```
      if(!Temp_List.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("Temp_List is not empty !");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared **if**  as **If** in your code.It should be in lowercase.

```
public void Check()
        {
            if(!Temp_List.isEmpty())
            {
                System.out.println("Temp_List is not empty !");
            }
        }
```